# ChessboardJs: Javascript Boards Work Only The First Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*Edit: The page code can be found on my page URL. I don't know where the fault might be. Please help.*

**Problem:**

When we click to the chess puzzles page for the first time, they work. However, the boards vanish when we re-click to them from the homepage.

**Demo:**

This is the home page.

[image]

You click on a player's picture and you are taken to this page. Please note that the boards appear in this one.

[image]

But you see that link to go back to the puzzle list. You click on that and you land on the home page again.

Now, if you click on any of the players' photo (or even the same player's photo), this is what you get.

[image]

From now on, none of the puzzle links would work.

**You can check it yourself at [chess-puzzle.com](https://chess-puzzle.com).**

**Few information:**

The site used Cloudfare. I tested with Cloudfare (inactive) a few minutes back yet the problem is not resolved.

I validated JS and it seems to be okay.

I have only one CSS file on my own (mycss.css). Other external files came with the piece of software.

I don't know which code to share because I don't know why this might happen. Though I can share any code by editing this question if asked for.

Can anybody please provide an answer to this.

Comment: How do you imagine that we can give you an answer when we only see images, There best answer I could give you with the amount of information is that you might have an error in your code. If you wish to get more and better errors please provide us with all relevant code.

Comment: I already shared my page URL. You can see the page code from there. And apart from that, it is using the chessboardjs.com package. It's a big package. It would not be feasible to share it all here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the attribute `async` in the scripts (jquery, chessboard) and that means that they do not load in any particular order.

But, the chessboard uses jquery at some points so if the chessboard script loads/runs first it will crash because it does not find jquery.

The script at the bottom will also fail as it might run before jQuery is loaded.

Finally you have included the chessboard script twice in the `head.

The best solution for your case would be to move the scripts at the bottom of the `body`, right above your inline script and remove the `async` attribute from them.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriele. I kept only the min files.